# mutate columns to detect number of variants

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am new in R. I have a data frame with many reference and many samples. I would like to write function to count the number of variants, for instances, if the genotype of sample is equal to ref column, it is 0, if it is equal to het column, it is 1 and if it is equal to risk column, it goes 2.

```
df:
SNP    ref  het risk Sample1 Sample2 ...
rs1     GG  AG  AA  AG  GG
rs2     AA  AG  GG  AG  AA
rs3     AA  AG  GG  AG  AG
rs4     GG  AG  AA  AG  AA
rs5     GG  AG  AA  AG  AA
rs6     GG  AG  AA  AG  AG
rs7     AA  AG  GG  AA  AA
rs8     CC  AC  AA  AC  CC
rs9     GG  AG  AA  GG  GG
rs10    GG  AG  AA  GG  AG
rs11    AA  AG  GG  AA  GG
rs12    GG  AG  AA  AA  AG
rs13    GG  AG  AA  AG  AA
rs14    AA  AG  GG  AG  AA
rs15    GG  AG  AA  AA  AA
rs16    AA  AC  CC  AA  AA
rs17    AA  AG  GG  AA  AA
rs18    GG  AG  AA  GG  GG
rs19    GG  AG  AA  GG  AG
rs20    GG  AG  AA  AG  AG
...

desired output:
SNP     ref het risk Sample1 Sample2 Sample1.vd Sample2.vd ...
rs1     GG  AG  AA  AG  GG  1   0
rs2     AA  AG  GG  AG  AA  1   0
rs3     AA  AG  GG  AG  AG  1   1
rs4     GG  AG  AA  AG  AA  1   2
rs5     GG  AG  AA  AG  AA  1   2
rs6     GG  AG  AA  AG  AG  1   1
rs7     AA  AG  GG  AA  AA  0   0
rs8     CC  AC  AA  AC  CC  1   0
rs9     GG  AG  AA  GG  GG  0   0
rs10    GG  AG  AA  GG  AG  0   1
rs11    AA  AG  GG  AA  GG  0   2
rs12    GG  AG  AA  AA  AG  2   1
rs13    GG  AG  AA  AG  AA  1   2
rs14    AA  AG  GG  AG  AA  1   0
rs15    GG  AG  AA  AA  AA  2   2
rs16    AA  AC  CC  AA  AA  0   0
rs17    AA  AG  GG  AA  AA  0   0
rs18    GG  AG  AA  GG  GG  0   0
rs19    GG  AG  AA  GG  AG  0   1
rs20    GG  AG  AA  AG  AG  1   1   
...
```

I tried to write a function then use apply function.

```
VariantDetected <- function(df) {
x <- which(df[5:length(df)] == df[,c("ref","het","risk_hom")])
return(x)
}
apply(df, 1, VariantDetected)
```

But it comes up with error, any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dplyr package is easier as it makes your code more readable. If you don't mind the datatype of your columns you can delete the second last line in the function. I hope it helps you.

```
#Needed library---------
library(dplyr)
# Your function------------
VariantDetected <- function(dataset) {
df1 <- data.frame(sapply(dataset, function(x) as.character(x)),stringsAsFactors = F)
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Sample1.vd = ifelse(Sample1 == ref,0,ifelse(Sample1 == het,1,2)),
                    Sample2.vd = ifelse(Sample2 == ref,0,ifelse(Sample2 == het,1,2)))
df1[1:6] <- data.frame(sapply(df1[1:6], function(x) as.factor(x))) # you can delete this line if you dont mind the first 6 columns to be charecters
return(df1)
}
#execute it on your dataset-----------
df <- VariantDetected(df)
```

Regards/Revanth Nemani

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need nested `ifelse` here

```
df[paste0("Sample", seq_along(5:ncol(df)), ".vd")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) 
                  ifelse(x[5:length(x)] == x["ref"], 0,
                  ifelse(x[5:length(x)] == x["het"], 1, 2))))


df
#    SNP ref het risk Sample1 Sample2 Sample1.vd Sample2.vd
#1   rs1  GG  AG   AA      AG      GG          1          0
#2   rs2  AA  AG   GG      AG      AA          1          0
#3   rs3  AA  AG   GG      AG      AG          1          1
#4   rs4  GG  AG   AA      AG      AA          1          2
#5   rs5  GG  AG   AA      AG      AA          1          2
#6   rs6  GG  AG   AA      AG      AG          1          1
#7   rs7  AA  AG   GG      AA      AA          0          0
#8   rs8  CC  AC   AA      AC      CC          1          0
#9   rs9  GG  AG   AA      GG      GG          0          0
#10 rs10  GG  AG   AA      GG      AG          0          1
#....
```

Or if you want to use it as a function

```
VariantDetected <- function(x) {
   ifelse(x[5:length(x)] == x["ref"], 0,
        ifelse(x[5:length(x)] == x["het"], 1, 2))
}

df[paste0("Sample", seq_along(5:ncol(df)), ".vd")]<-t(apply(df, 1, VariantDetected))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(SNP = structure(c(1L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L), .Label = 
c("rs1", 
"rs10", "rs11", "rs12", "rs13", "rs14", "rs15", "rs16", "rs17", 
"rs18", "rs19", "rs2", "rs20", "rs3", "rs4", "rs5", "rs6", "rs7", 
"rs8", "rs9"), class = "factor"), ref = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("AA", "CC", "GG"), class = "factor"), het = 
structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AC", "AG"), class = "factor"), risk = 
structure(c(1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "CC", "GG"), class = "factor"), 
Sample1 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AA", 
"AC", "AG", "GG"), class = "factor"), Sample2 = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AA", "AG", "CC", "GG"), class = "factor"), 
Sample1.vd = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Sample2.vd = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), .Names = c("SNP", "ref", "het", "risk", "Sample1", "Sample2", 
"Sample1.vd", "Sample2.vd"), class = "data.frame")
```